# When i use 127.0.0.1 as proxy,i can't access any websites

Tags: ssl, firefox, localhost, http-proxy, insecure-connection

I'm setting up Burp Suite, in the process i had to manually configure the proxy to LocalIp:127.0.0.1 Port: 8080 in firefox. after doing this,whenever i try to open any website i get an error saying 
**Your connection is not secure**

**The owner of www.google.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.
This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox may only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
Learn more…
Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites
www.youtube.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates.
An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER**
but if i don't use any proxy i can access the web,but in order to use Burp Suite i have to use a proxy(127.0.0.1,8080) Please guide me,i'm a newbie
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

P.S: i have configured my local host but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because Burp act as proxy and have own certificate (which is not the same as google certificate). You should accept this certificate in the browser you use.

Comment: i'm able to open pages when the intercept is off when it is on the pages keeps on loading but i'm getting the packets in http history is this normal behaviour of Burp Suite?

Comment: @yajnaRohit, I am not an expert for this product, but probably yes. Intercept for me mean exactly this (store, but not proxy to end user)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite many steps to set Burp Suite working on `localhost`, for example, to run this on `Firefox` you might need:

1. `Burp`'s certificate accessible via `http://burp`. Get the certificate from the URL, install and restart `Firefox`.
2. Make sure your port is free, sometimes the default's `8080` is being used by different applications. Change this in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options` -> `Edit` on the desired proxy listener.
3. Set up the same proxy details in `Firefox` having the `Manual proxy configuration` option enabled, which you can see in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options`.
4. In `Firefox` you might need type `about:config` in the URL and set `network.security.ports.banned.override` to `PORT_NUMBER` (the same one which is in `Burp Suite` -> `Proxy` -> `Options` -> `Edit` and therefore in `Firefox`'s proxy - yes, point 3.).
5. In `Firefox` you might need type `about:config` in the URL and set `network.proxy.allow.hijacking_localhost` to `true`.
6. Sometimes you might need to read more about **upstream proxy** if you have an additional proxy on your local machine, however in my case it was not required.